# Is it possible to get a popup to ignore MenuDropAlignment in a WPF / Touch app?

Tags: wpf, xaml, touch, multi-touch, multidatatrigger

As a bit of background - Windows has a facility for Touch/TabletPCs whereby it shifts the position of popups/menus depending on your "handedness" (to prevent the menu appearing under your hand).

Essentially what this does is if you are set to "right handed" (which it seems to default to once you've connected a touch device), every popup you open is artificially kicked to the left - this causes massive layout issues where we try and line up a popup with the item it "popped up from" :

**Tablet PC Settings set to Left handed - no artificial correction from Windows**
[image: Tablet PC Settings set to Left handed - no artificial correction from Windows]

**Tablet PC Settings set to Right handed - Windows artificially adjusts our positioning**
[image: Tablet PC Settings set to Right handed - Windows artificially adjusts our positioning]

We can detect what this setting is set to with [SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.menudropalignment.aspx), and for trivial popups we can adjust this using the actual width of the popup - but for dynamic popups and when we throw right to left support into the mix, this just doesn't work.

Currently it's looking more likely that we are going to have to go through every popup, manually work out a value to adjust the kick, and add something like this to every one:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment}}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=FlowDirection}" Value="RightToLeft"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="-50"/> <!-- Set to arbitrary value to test -->
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

So.. back to the question :-) Does anyone know of a way to stop a WPF popup looking at this setting at all?

For those that don't have a touch device you can access the Tablet PC settings by running:

C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}

And see the mess it makes for yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear this just isn't possible, so we are resorting to the MultiDataTrigger in the question to compensate.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a custom popup that solve this problem: you can set the ForceAlignment dependency property and open it with the "Open" method, or you can directly call "OpenLeft" and "OpenRight" methods.

```vb
Public Class CustomPopup

Inherits Primitives.Popup
Private Shared moFI As Reflection.FieldInfo = GetType(SystemParameters).GetField("_menuDropAlignment", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic + Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)

Public Enum enuForceAlignment
    None = 0
    Left
    Right
End Enum

Public Property ForceAlignment As enuForceAlignment
    Get
        Return GetValue(ForceAlignmentProperty)
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As enuForceAlignment)
        SetValue(ForceAlignmentProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Public Shared ReadOnly ForceAlignmentProperty As DependencyProperty = _
                       DependencyProperty.Register("ForceAlignment", _
                       GetType(enuForceAlignment), GetType(CustomPopup), _
                       New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(enuForceAlignment.None))

Public Sub Open()
    Select Case ForceAlignment
        Case enuForceAlignment.Left
            OpenLeft()
        Case enuForceAlignment.Right
            OpenRight()
        Case Else
            IsOpen = True
    End Select
End Sub
Public Sub OpenRight()
    _Open(False)
End Sub
Public Sub OpenLeft()
    _Open(True)
End Sub
Private Sub _Open(paMenuDropAlignment As Boolean)
    If SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment <> paMenuDropAlignment Then
        moFI.SetValue(Nothing, paMenuDropAlignment)
        IsOpen = True
        moFI.SetValue(Nothing, Not paMenuDropAlignment)
    Else
        IsOpen = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't think this answer gets enough credit.

It's a bit hidden in there, but if you do this, you can essentially turn this off systemwide in two lines:


            FieldInfo fi = typeof(SystemParameters).GetField("_menuDropAlignment",
               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

            fi.SetValue(null, false);

Comment: This doesn't work system wide consistently - it seems to have an effect for a short period of time, but resets. It works fine in the context of the example - setting just before opening - but unfortunately you can't just set it once.

Comment: Follow up to my previous comment - you can make the setting "stick" by calling the SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment property first - e.g. if you have "if (SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment)" before the reflection setting code, the value you set appears to stick, otherwise it is reset.

Answer (score 2):

Set it to regular mode for your whole application:

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(SystemParameters).GetField("_menuDropAlignment",
   BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

fi.SetValue(null, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but I found another way if you have .net 4.5 at least.

By overriding your menuitem/popup templates, you can use the following trigger:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment)}" Value="[True/False]">
    <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="Placement" Value="[Left/Right]"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Off course, set the following :

- True or False to your datatrigger value,
- Left or Right as your setter value.

It's important that the binding use Binding Path=() syntax and not Binding={x:static ...} so that you can use the StaticPropertyChanged event from your static class.

Answer (score 0):

`SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment` is used in a single method:

`System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.GetPointCombination()`

This private method has logic that depends upon the value of `Popup.Placement`, which is of type `PlacementMode`:

```
public enum PlacementMode
{
    Absolute,
    Relative,
    Bottom,
    Center,
    Right,
    AbsolutePoint,
    RelativePoint,
    Mouse,
    MousePoint,
    Left,
    Top,
    Custom
}
```

In `GetPointCombination()`, it only checks the `MenuDropAlignment` when the `PlacementMode` is `Relative`, `AbsolutePoint`, `RelativePoint`, or `MousePoint`. If you can use one of the other `PlacementModes` then you won't be subject to the `MenuDropAlignment` check.

If you use `PlacementMode.Custom`, then you'll also want to set the `Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback` to a valid method in order to provide your popup's `CustomPopupPlacement[]` coordinates.

Source: Reflector

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this one - but I've just checked reflector myself and MenuDropAlignment is used for every item in the enum apart from Center, and Center is no good because it then (as far as I can see) always slides down rather than up.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Julican's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960944/11874031) if you don't use the StaticPropertyChanged event

```
<Popup.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Popup">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Right"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.MenuDropAlignment}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Left"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Popup.Style>
```

In the code above values might differ depending on what you want...
Also, make sure that you didn't place the Placement property on the popup:

```
<Popup
    ...
    Placement="Right"
    ...
/>
```